# Image not displayed from static

Tags: python, html, django, image, csv

I am using a csv file to display an image on my django template. The csv file is like

```
id | Name  | image
-- | ----- | --------------------
 1 | wine1 | images\download1.jpg
```

i have kept the image in the static file

my  `wine_list.html` is as

```
{% for wine in wine_list %}
    <div>
        <h4><a href="{% url 'reviews:wine_detail' wine.id %}">
        {{ wine.name}}</a><br>
        {% if wine.description != "nan" %}
        <h4>{{ wine.description }}</h4>
        {% else %}
        <h1> No Description available 
        {% endif %}     
        <h3>'{{ wine.images.url }}'</h3>
        <br>
        <a>  <img src="{% static '{{ wine.images.url }}' %}" height="200"></a>
```

the name and description shows fine, and the

> wine.images.url

prints

> images/download.jpg

shouldn't the image be printed ?

my image folder is in my static, when i print it like this

```
<a>  <img src="{% static 'images/download.jpg' %}" height="200"></a>
```

it does display the image.

Answer (score 1):

Just simply use `wine.images.url` as a param of `static`

```
<img src="{% static wine.images.url %}" height="200">
```

Answer (score 0):

The provided answer doesn't work for me, but this does:

```
src="{{ wine.image.url }}"
```

Comment: Your answer is correct when `STATIC_URL` settings is set to `/`.

Comment: @TomaszJakubRup ahh yeah, you are right. I just realized I haven't done collectstatic yet in this project.